# Plot a set of negative data in the "positive" Y-axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a set of data I want to plot in MATLAB, the problem is that this set of data is all negative. I want to plot it in the Y-axis as if it was positive so the plot remains on the first quadrant, and I also want that the values show as negative.

I obviously tried:

```
plot(x,-y);
```

But this does not work because it plots on the first quadrant, but the values are converted into positive.

Any help on how to do this? I have searched documentation and forums and I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking to reverse the direction in which the values on the `y`-axis grow?

```
x = -rand(100,1); %// some negative data
figure;
ah = axes;
plot(1:100, x);
%// reverse the direction in which values on y-axis increase
set(ah,'ydir','reverse')
```

For more, see [axes properties](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html), especially `XDir`, `YDir`, and `ZDir`.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the labels of your y-axis. Here's an example solution:

```
x = 1:10;
y = -1:-1:-10;

plot(x,abs(y))
ax = gca;
ax.YTick = abs(y);
ax.YTickLabel = num2cell(y);
```

Comment: While this solution will technically work, you will have side effects such as the data cursor tool tip showing wrong `y` values. I really don't see the point considering that changing the `YDir` property saves you from all that, and is simpler.